# Post a comment from HTML to C# model in a list using MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have tried several fixes, but not seem to fit. I am creating a post and comment partial classes that go onto a main page. I would like to allow an end user to add comments. I am using MVC 5 and currently the page loads the posts and older comments.

However, I am trying to use the onclick method on the client side to connect to my server side. Then in the javascript, I attempt to use a call to ajax to send a call to the location of the c# method. The button doesn't seem to even realize it is being clicked. I have the post partial class nested on the main page. Code below

**Post view**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC_5_Skeleton1.Models.Post>
<ul class="mylist">
@{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    if (Model.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {        
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.newComment, "NewComment", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control-inline", placeholder = "Who are you" })
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" onclick="AddToCart(@item.newComment)">Post</button>                              
        }
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    function AddToCart(comment) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Controller/GetTest',
            data: { comment: comment },
        }).done(function () {
        alert('Added');
    });
}</script>
```

**Controller...I have tried both with and without HTTPPOST**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetTest(String M)
{
    return M();
}
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint in your javascript before the $.ajax, or a console.log("blah") in the same place, does it get hit?

Comment: I do get an output with a console.log when the page loads. However, not when the button is clicked. Also, the break point doesn't even stop on the button when I click it.

Comment: can you please post the rendered html with the button code that you're outputting. Also, you shouldn't be hitting a console.log inside that function on page load, unless you're calling that method on page load...

Comment: Its unclear what your trying do do here. `onclick="AddToCart(@item.newComment)` will only send the initial value of `newComment` (not any edited value) so all you would be doing is posting back the original value (what would be the point). And what is `return M();`?

Comment: And your sending back a value named `comment` but your parameter name in the method is `String M`, not `string comment` so `M` will always be `null`

Comment: The return M was just me trying to make sure the code was actually running through.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax function, add this parameter

```
type: "POST",
```

And rename the `(string M)` in your controller action by `(string comment)`

Comment: Well it runs to the ajax now, but not to the controller method.

Comment: Alright it works now...my brilliant brain forgot that the controller was not           "name"-controller just the name no controller to follow